# Can anyone tell me why Gnome 3 looks like as if it were a gnome fallback session in my virtualbox?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, gnome-classic

For some reason Gnome 3 wont work in my virtualbox. Both gnome classic and gnome look exactly identical.

The version of my virtualbox is: 4.1.2_ Ubuntu r38459
The 3D acceleration is on in the virtualbox and the Guest Additions is installed in the virtualbox from the software center.

Obviously, the graphic card driver is installed on the main Ubuntu system I am using with my laptop. (although the post-release updates can't be installed for whatever reason)

Gnome shell is installed from the software center in the virtualbox.

Now the issue is that the gnome and gnome classic look like just the same.

Here is an image of what gnome looks like (so does gnome classic too....so I am only posting one image):

[image]

What causes this issue?

By the way....I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome fallback session.

**NOTE:** I have been asked to use the `~$ gnome-shell --replace` command.
It basically made the fallback mode into the desired Gnome 3 desktop environment till the next restart, but that's it.

I got this message in the terminal though:

```
~$ gnome-shell --replace
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error registering polkit authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject (polkit-error-quark 0)

(gnome-shell:1860): folks-WARNING **: Failed to find primary PersonaStore with type ID 'eds' and ID 'system'.
Individuals will not be linked properly and creating new links between Personas will not work.
The configured primary PersonaStore's backend may not be installed. If you are unsure, check with your distribution.
```

**UPDATE:** this is the image of the additional drivers. As you can see one can't be installed and this is why it's not active.
[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer below with a workaround. Not ideal but a solid way to get around installing the graphics drivers within the virtualbox as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a graphical error. Running gnome-shell on a machine (in this case virtualbox) that doesnt meet the requirements will fall back on the classic/fallback session.

Try:

- open a terminal ( `Ctrl+Alt+T` )
- replacing the current session with the shell ( `gnome-shell --replace` )

This will try replace fallback session with the shell, if it fails at least you will be able to see why because the errors will be output in the terminal.

Updating the question with any errors will help us to help you.

**UPDATE: Workaround...**

I believe that gnome-shell is failing an accelerated hardware check which takes place when the session is loaded. A workaround would be to load the gnome-shell when you log into the gnome-classic session.

You can do this by creating a file called `gnome-shell.desktop`, save it to ~/.config/autostart/
Inside it put the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-shell --replace
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en]=Gnome Shell Startup
Name=Gnome Shell Startup
Comment[en]=
Comment=
OnlyShowIn=GNOME
AutostartCondition=GNOME3 if-session gnome-classic
```

There is a difference between gnome-classic and gnome-fallback (classic loads with some effects), if you don't have classic installed change `gnome-classic` on the last line to `gnome-fallback`

you will know if its installed if you have 2 Gnome Classic options in your session menu - one will have "(no effects)" written next to it

Comment: There is a little bit of a problem Captain: there is no .config/autostart in the virtualbox. I have found that folder on the main OS, but nothing in the virtualbox. I have obviously pressed CTRL+H. So that is not the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing this is probably because no applications are set to start at startup yet. Try creating the directory yourself aswell.

Comment: I have tried that too. I am giving up on Gnome 3. For some reason it just wont work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We could have one last shot! open a terminal, type `gnome-session-properties`, click "Add", Name: Gnome Shell, Command: `gnome-shell --replace`, Comment: last shot at starting gnome shell in virtualbox!

Comment: This helped, but the animations and the way it behaves in the virtualbox is pretty weird. I might try it on my laptop (if it works better there), but can you do me a big favour and tell me what is happening? Why do I neeed the --replace in the first place?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure. I'd think if it didn't boot from the session menu it wouldn't work with `--replace`. There is a file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.session` which sets I believe is the basic session startup file. There are two required components **gnome-shell** and **gnome-settings-daemon**, I would think these are both installed (you can try install them to  double check) but by the sounds of the buggy animations I think it must be graphics. Have you tried the proprietary drivers inside the virtualbox?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the driver. Although there are 2 drivers, one is an update and my system fails to install that one. I have just updated the main message with a screenshot of my additional drivers.

Comment: This looks like you have drivers installed. You can normally only have one or the other and the post-release updates driver has never worked/installed for me! tbh, I don't think there is much more we can do here, will probably work better installed on your actual machine. Give it a go, personally I'm not a fan of KDE, gnome-shell or unity.... thinking about switching to openbox!

Comment: I am just reading about openbox. It says that Xfce uses it as its window manager. I guess I'll give the Xfce DE a go too.